# from a list of strings, how do you get the strangest word/string in python

Tags: python

I have a list of strings:

```
['twas', 'brillig', 'and', 'the', 'slithy', 'toves', 'did', 'gyre', 'and', 'gimble', 'in', 'the', 'wabe', 'all', 'mimsy', 'were', 'the', 'borogoves', 'and', 'the', 'mome', 'raths', 'outgrabe', '"beware', 'the', 'jabberwock', 'my', 'son', 'the', 'jaws', 'that', 'bite', 'the', 'claws', 'that', 'catch', 'beware', 'the', 'jubjub', 'bird', 'and', 'shun', 'the', 'frumious', 'bandersnatch', 'he', 'took', 'his', 'vorpal', 'sword', 'in', 'hand', 'long', 'time', 'the', 'manxome', 'foe', 'he', 'sought', 'so', 'rested', 'he', 'by', 'the', 'tumtum', 'tree', 'and', 'stood', 'awhile', 'in', 'thought', 'and', 'as', 'in', 'uffish', 'thought', 'he', 'stood', 'the', 'jabberwock', 'with', 'eyes', 'of', 'flame', 'came', 'whiffling', 'through', 'the', 'tulgey', 'wood', 'and', 'burbled', 'as', 'it', 'came', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'and', 'through', 'and', 'through', 'the', 'vorpal', 'blade', 'went', 'snicker-snack', 'he', 'left', 'it', 'dead', 'and', 'with', 'its', 'head', 'he', 'went', 'galumphing', 'back', '"and', 'has', 'thou', 'slain', 'the', 'jabberwock', 'come', 'to', 'my', 'arms', 'my', 'beamish', 'boy', 'o', 'frabjous', 'day', 'callooh', 'callay', 'he', 'chortled', 'in', 'his', 'joy', '`twas', 'brillig', 'and', 'the', 'slithy', 'toves', 'did', 'gyre', 'and', 'gimble', 'in', 'the', 'wabe', 'all', 'mimsy', 'were', 'the', 'borogoves', 'and', 'the', 'mome', 'raths', 'outgrabe']
```

How do I return a list of word(s) which are most different from other words in the string - based on the minimum similarity with all other words in the list and the average similarity value(as a float).

I have absolutley no idea how to do this. I think I need to use the cossim(word1,word2) function which calculates the similarity between 'word1' and 'word2' as we were given this function by our lecturer, but I do not know how to use it.

```
def cossim(word1,word2):
"""Calculate the cosine similarity between the two words"""

# sub-function for constructing a letter vector from argument `word`
# which returns the tuple `(vec,veclen)`, where `vec` is a dictionary of
# characters in `word`, and `veclen` is the length of the vector
def wordvec(word):
    vec = defaultdict(int)  # letter vector

    # count the letters in the word
    for char in word:
        vec[char] += 1

    # calculate the length of the letter vector
    len = 0.0
    for char in vec:
        len += vec[char]**2

    # return the letter vector and vector length
    return vec,math.sqrt(len)

# calculate a vector,length tuple for each of `word1` and `word2`
vec1,len1 = wordvec(word1)
vec2,len2 = wordvec(word2)

# calculate the dot product between the letter vectors for the two words
dotprod = 0.0
for char in vec1:
    dotprod += vec1[char]*vec2[char]

# divide by the lengths of the two vectors
if dotprod:
    dotprod /= len1*len2

return dotprod
```

The answer I should get from the list above should be:

```
({'my'], 0.088487238234566931)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Thanks,

Keely

Comment: "we were given this function by out lecturer" Well *we* don't have it, so what do you expect *us* to do?

Comment: Can you please include this cossim function?

Comment: i reedited my question and it is now there

Comment: Do you understand how to call the function? Do you understand how to get the minimum of a bunch of values? The average? What exactly is the problem? Have you attempted to describe how to get the answer, step by step?

Comment: `based on the minimum similarity with all other words in the list and the average similarity value(as a float).` is really ambiguous. I think that if you define your problem better, you would be able to find a solution much more easily.

Comment: that was what our lecturer gave us. in exactly those words and i wrote them on here like that because i didnt really know what he meant. I have worked it out now anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The list of words needs to be deduplicated *first* before using an approach like Robert Rossney suggested.  Otherwise the resulting number will be slightly off because the same `w` can appear multiple times in one `d[word]`.

One possible way to do this would be to create a set from the list:

```
set_of_words = set(mylist)
differences = {}
for word in set_of_words:
    differences[word] = [cossim(word, word2) for word2 in set_of_words if word != word2]
```

This creates a dictionary assigning to each word a list of differences to each other word.

Instead of assigning these lists directly to the dictionary entries you could also save them in a variable within the loop and calculate the avg like afg suggested in Robert's solution, using that variable.

The dictionary function [iteritems](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) lets you iterate over `(key, value)`-pairs and the [min](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#min) function has a special parameter `key` to specify what to minimize, for example `key=lambda x: x[1]` to sort by the second element of a tuple or list.

Comment: This is good advice, but probably should have been a comment on Robert's answer. It's hard to know on homework questions like this, but for other types of questions this wouldn't qualify as an answer.

Comment: Sorry I don't have enough rep for commenting, otherwise I would have done that.

Comment: It's fine, especially with your edit -- I just wanted to give you some general advice since I saw you were a new user.

Answer (score 1):

For a starting point, you probably want to construct a dictionary whose keys are the words in the list and whose values are all of the *other* words in the list:

```
d = {}
for word in mylist:
   d[word] = [w for w in mylist if w != word]
```

This gives you a quick way of computing the similarity values for each word:

```
similarities = {}
for word in mylist:
   similarities[word] = [cossim(w, word) for w in d[word]]
```

From that it's easy to calculate the minimum and average similarities for each word.

Comment: i am a beginner and do not really know how to calculate the minimum and average similarites for each word

Comment: @KeelyAranyos We're not going to do your homework for you. In Python, you can calculate a minimum with the `min` function. You can calculate the average of a sequence as `sum(sequence) / len(sequence)`.

Answer (score 1):

So the goal, if I understand correctly, is to find the word with the minimum sum of cossim with all of the other words. For that, the following code would suffice:

```
/* removed at the reasonable request of agf */
```

From a high-level perspective, what we're doing is looping through each word in your list, and checking to see how similar it is to all the other words. If it is less similar than any of the other words we've seen thus far, we store it. Our output is then the word with the lowest similarity with all other words.

Comment: Please don't give near-complete answers to homework questions.

Comment: when i do that, it returns:

    ('outgrabe', 55.716288505579705)

Our lecturer told us we should get: ({'my'], 0.088487238234566931)

Comment: I didn't mean for you to remove it completely. Pseudocode or code with crucial lines replaced with comments describing what to do there is what I often post to questions like this. Your description is good, regardless.

Answer (score 0):

i think the module Python-Levenshtein [(pypi link)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/0.11.2)may help get the similarity of word1 and word2:

use two functions:

```
import Levenshtein

str1 = 'abcde'
str2 = 'abcdf'
print(Levenshtein.distance(str1,str2))
# 1
print(Levenshtein.ratio(str1,str2))
# 0.8
```

is enough.